# Is Datastax enterprize free to use in production environment?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am using datastax enterprize 5.1 version in Analytics mode. Is it free to use in production environment?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is only free in development

Comment: You mean, I can only use DSE when I need to test my code to write into DSE's Cassandra and to test my code for Spark(I am using Spark of DSE). But when I need to deploy it as a live server where my all the apps will use this server , then I can not use DSE. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I got my answer here.
https://www.datastax.com/2011/11/datastax-enterprise-now-completely-free-for-development-use

Comment: You can develop all you want in DSE in development, but would need a subscription to run DSE in prod. There is a huge caveat here in that what you develop in DSE development will be using DSE drivers and DSE functionality that may or may not be in OSS C* so be careful